# Cypress : How can we write GET request in with bearer token in cypress?

Tags: javascript, networking, get, request, cypress

I have two requests: one is POST request and other is get. In first i get user access token by post and in other i used this accessToken to get login. My code does not work.

I am using window 7 and cypress 3.3.5

my code:

```
var value;
describe("Login operation", () => {
  it("Login Request with post method", () => {
    cy.request({
      method:'POST', 
      url:'https://odms.baitussalam.org:8445/api/v1/auth/login',
      body: {
        "userName": "faizanj",
        "password": "abc"
      }
    })
      .then(function(response){
        this.value = response.body.accessToken;
        console.log("Value "+this.value);

        expect(response.body.name).to.equal('Faizan');
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
      });
  });

  it('Second test case', function() {

    var authHeader='bearer ${'+this.value+'}';
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://odms.baitussalam.org:8445/api/v1/qurbani-representative`,
      headers:{
        authorization:authHeader,
      }};

    cy.request(options)
      .then((response)=>{
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200);6+9
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try putting a `console.log(this.value)` in your second test to see if the header is even using the value. I don't think you need the `this.` in front of `value`, but you can confirm it this way.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that you are trying using variable set between test cases when it's already reset to store token you need either use global variable (not advised), or create some login command that will be called before you need access to token. For example:

```js
Cypress.Commands.Add('login', (userName, password) => {
  cy.request({
      method:'POST', 
      url:'https://odms.baitussalam.org:8445/api/v1/auth/login',
      body: {
        userName,
        password,
      }
    })
    .as('loginResponse')
    .then((response) => {
      Cypress.env('token', response.body.accessToken); // either this or some global var but remember that this will only work in one test case
      return response;
    })
    .its('status')
    .should('eq', 200);
})
```

Then whenever you need you login user before using `Cypress.env('token')`.

For example:

```js
describe('testing token', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login();
  });

  it('test request', () => {
    const token = Cypress.env('token');
    const authorization = `bearer ${ token }`;
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://odms.baitussalam.org:8445/api/v1/qurbani-representative`,
      headers: {
        authorization,
      }};

    cy.request(options)
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200);
  })
});
```

You can go further and override all request to add token to them like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('request', (originalFn, ...options) => {
  const optionsObject = options[0];
  const token = Cypress.env('token');

  if (!!token && optionsObject === Object(optionsObject)) {
    optionsObject.headers = {
      authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      ...optionsObject.headers,
    };

    return originalFn(optionsObject);
  }

  return originalFn(...options);
});
```

then the above example would look like this:

```js
describe('testing token', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login();
  });

  it('test request', () => {
    cy.request(options)
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200);
  })
});
```

Comment: The request overwrite doesnt seem to work. If I do it along with cy.request(url, {Headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token}), it works. Please advice.

Comment: @a2441918 you can try debugging if you have correctly setup for `Cypress.env('token')` in overwrite it is probably empty if you need to add it separately in `cy.request`. If this is the case you need to run `cy.login();` (as defined above) before running any `cy.request`