# How would I get the value from the hidden input using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I need to save the token which is stored in this hidden input.

This is my request:

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/auth/login',
  body: {
    email: email,
    password: password,
  },
}).then((response) => {
    const page = response.body;
});
```

The `response.body` returns:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form class="form" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="c5LWQtrMVkKXxBFKs1zFzrJYq4PgNifndvcV0F6O">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <a href="https://testing.com">Other Login</a>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how I find/grab the value from the hidden input with the name `_token`

Comment: Here is a similar question with a brief explanation of the answer. 

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817348/8287839

You will find out how and where to add Token.

Comment: Have you tried the examples in cypress docs? https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes#Logging-In ... especially this one looks similar https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the cypress [CSRF example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/cypress-4/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens/cypress/integration/logging-in-csrf-tokens-spec.js):

```
  it('strategy #1: parse token from HTML', function () {

    // to fetch the login page, and then parse the HTML contents
    // to find the CSRF token embedded in the page
    cy.request('/auth/login')
    .its('body')
    .then((body) => {
      // we can use Cypress.$ to parse the string body
      // thus enabling us to query into it easily
      const $html = Cypress.$(body)
      const token = $html.find('input[name=_token]').val()

      ...[see link for full code]
    })
```

*Note*: above example is for cypress v4. For latest cypress version, see [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens).

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be exactly what I was looking for.